# Kusto: query to group http status codes

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to query some Azure Application Gateway related things from Azure Log Analytics.

I get for a query like this results for every single http status code:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK" and Category == "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog"
| summarize count() by httpStatus_d, Resource
```

Now I need those results grouped for 2xx, 3xx, 4xx and 5xx.

New to Kusto I don't find the right approach to achieve this.
Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using the `bin()` function, e.g.:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK" and Category == "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog"
| summarize count() by bin(httpStatus_d, 100), Resource
```

Comment: Thanks @yoni
What if i want to have a timechart for the single groups? So, four line for 2xx, 3xx, 4xx and 5xx?

Comment: you could try something like: `AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK" and Category == "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog"
| summarize count() by StatusGroup = bin(httpStatus_d, 100), bin(timestamp, 1h) | render timechart`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @yoni who sent me into the right direction.

I solved this like this:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK" and Category == "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog"
| extend HTTPStatus = case(httpStatus_d between (200 .. 299), "2XX",
                       httpStatus_d between (300 .. 399), "3XX",
                       httpStatus_d between (400 .. 499), "4XX",
                       "5XX")
| summarize count() by HTTPStatus, bin(timeStamp_t, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by all httpStatus_d values automatically.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| summarize count=count() by httpStatus_d
| order by httpStatus_d asc
```